# Verifying the minimum degree of a geometric predicate

Tags: cg.comp-geom, polynomials

Let $F = (f_1, \ldots, f_n)$ be a sequence of multivariate polynomials $f_i : \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$, and $g : \{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}$ a boolean function.  Say the composition
$$h(x)=g(f_1(x)>0,\ldots,f_n(x)>0)$$
answers some useful geometric question (e.g., is the intersection of two circles inside a third?).  Let $\deg(F) = \max_i \deg(f_i)$ be the maximum degree of any of the polynomials.

*Question*: Is there an algorithm to check whether $\deg(F)$ can be reduced without changing $h(x)$?  Are there practical implementations of such (perhaps in Mathematica or Sage)?

I believe this is essentially a question of polynomial irreducibility, and the answer may be as simple as checking whether the highest degree $f_i$s factor.  However, since the answer may be simply be "yes, it's minimal", I want to be sure before I publish such a claim.

Comment: This should have been studied before. See maybe:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_algebraic_geometry Also, the book "Basu, Saugata; Pollack, Richard; Roy, Marie-Françoise Algorithms in real algebraic geometry" might be useful.

Comment: Wonderful, that looks like a terrific book!  I've been looking around for a good reference on algorithm semi-algebraic geometry and hadn't found one yet.  On the other hand, I think there's a good chance that algebraic geometry over $\mathbb{C}$ may be enough for this question, at least for a good number of predicates.  For example, after working through various predicates the semi- part seems to arise as lower degree structure, such as for a sign check before squaring both sides of an inequality, and may effect the maximum degree only weakly.

Comment: I suspect this is also well studied - but I do not know...